# How to disable key highlights when entering PIN code?

Tags: 8.0, keyboard, password, pin

When entering my PIN code, each number lights up as I tap it. This makes it easier for someone to read my PIN. Is there a way to disable this? It's possible in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't disable the keyboard highlighting when entering your pin yet. There is already a feature request on the [Windows Phone UserVoice](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6264473-don-t-highlight-numbers-when-entering-pin) page you should vote for.